# Debugging Internal Emails with Exchange 2003/2010

Tags: exchange-2003, exchange-2010, exchange-migration

I am in the middle of migrating from Exchange 2003 to Exchange 2010 SP1.

I have moved one mailbox over to the new server EXCHANGE2010 . For some reason if an internal email is sent from someone on EXCHANGE2003 (the old server), it is not delivered to the new mailbox on EXCHANGE2010.

Where should I look to debug this problem? What logs should I consult?

Update: I found the messages in Queues on the old server, listed as messages with an unreachable destination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it! You need to create a routing group between the old and the new server:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa997292.aspx

> This example creates reciprocal
>   routing group connectors between the
>   Exchange 2010 routing group and the
>   routing group associated with the
>   specified Exchange 2003 server,
>   assigns a cost of 10 to that
>   connector, and enables public folder
>   referrals.

```
 New-RoutingGroupConnector -Name "Interop RGC" -SourceTransportServers "Ex2010Hub1.contoso.com" -TargetTransportServers "Ex2003BH1.contoso.com" -Cost 10 -Bidirectional $true -PublicFolderReferralsEnabled $true
```